# How to getLocation of components in GroupLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, grouplayout

I have a problem. When I `getLocation` of button `b2`, it return 0-0. So can I get the location of `b2`?

```
 public class TestF {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("GroupLayout");
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

     GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(contentPane);

     contentPane.setLayout(groupLayout);

     JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
     JButton b2 = new JButton("Second Button");

     groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
         .addComponent(label).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(b2));

     groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(groupLayout
         .createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(label)
         .addComponent(b2));
       System.out.println(b2.getLocation());
     frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);
   }
 }
```

Comment: *"How to getLocation of components in GroupLayout?"* Why do you think you need to get the location? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) BTW - don't use 'quote formatting' for code segments.

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry for that. This is my first time of asking :D

Comment: Don't be sorry, be smart by answering my question. It was not rhetorical.

Comment: ya. I need to get location of button b2 to know distance from old location to new location when resize jframe. I'm not so good at English

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question. Why do you care about the distance the button moves when the frame is resized? Let the layout manager do its job. You should not care about the final outcome if you are using the appropriate layout manager for your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, i will find another way to resolve this problem without depend on distance. Let the layout manager do its job!

Comment: You still haven't stated what the problem is. If you are going to ask a question then you need to know what the problem is that you are asking about.